# How to find a similar API to the mock StackOverflow API?

Tags: rest, backend

I'm a front-end developer trying to practice by using the mock StackOverflow API that responds with JSON data.

How can I find a similar API?

Comment: `<response>StAcK oVeRfLoW</response>`

Comment: You can create your own mock apis sending similar json resonse as stackoverflow.
Try https://themockapis.in/